# Can't add member into MongoDB replica-set

Tags: mongodb

I am using the MongoDB 2.4.3, and following the wizard:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

But when adding the other members into replica-set, get the following error:

```
root@vm3:~# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
connecting to: test
rs1:PRIMARY> rs.add("vm1")
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: set name does not match the set name host vm1:27017 expects",
    "code" : 13145,
    "ok" : 0
}
rs1:PRIMARY> rs.add("vm4")
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: set name does not match the set name host vm4:27017 expects",
    "code" : 13145,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

vm1, vm3 and vm4 know each other because I configured their /etc/hosts files correctly.

Any idea? I don't understand what does this error message mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, just restart virtual machines, every thing is fine.

Answer (score 3):

After restarting all vms, it works now.

```
root@vm3:~# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
connecting to: test
rs1:PRIMARY> rs.add("vm4")
{ "ok" : 1 }
rs1:PRIMARY> rs.add("vm1")
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

Comment: VMs can be a pain the butt like that

Comment: it's unlikely to have anything to do with VMs - it's more likely you also had to restart mongod processes on those VMs - and they have to have the same --replSet <name> as your replSet <name> - it seems like they were not initially.

Comment: No, I restarted mongod processes but it didn't work. So I rebooted VMs. I am sure they were using the same replSet name in their /etc/mongodb.conf files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are re-installing a MongoDB instance, the replSet may be living in your data file on the drive.  I had the same problem setting up a new replica set.  The problem was from changing the replica set name after bringing up instances with an older replSet name.  I deleted the data files, ran my install scripts again and it worked just fine.